# Does having your page file on decrease the life expectancy of your hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, pagefile

If I have my page file turned on in Windows as opposed to having it turned off as shown below:

[image]

Would having the page file turned on decrease the life expectancy on my Hard Drive? If so, how much would the life decrease say with regular use? (4 hours a day)

I'm thinking it would decrease some just because there would be more writing to the hard drive, but I wasn't sure if it would be too negligible to even matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should only make a difference on a solid-state drive, since flash memory can only be written a finite number of times; on a conventional hard disk, it's not going to make enough of a difference to notice.

That said, if you can, you may wish to put your page file on a different hard disk from the one which contains most of the data you actually use for the performance benefit. Unless you have so much RAM installed that the system never needs to page anyway, keeping your page file on a separate disk will speed things up, because your accesses to the data you're using won't be constantly interrupted by accesses to the page file. (Of course, if you're using a RAID or have enough RAM that you never page anyway, this isn't a concern.)